# How to remove inputAccessoryView and replace it with another view?

Tags: ios, swift3, uikit

**Here is the requirement**

- Basic chat app that has an input accessory view on top of keyboard in a `UICollectionViewController`
- I add this custom input accessory view by using `override var inputAccessoryView` and I return the custom view in this function
- I have a requirement where I need to **replace** this `inputAccessoryView` with another custom input accessory view at some point for a particular functionality

**What I have tried**

- **Problem 1**: I tried `removeFromSuperView()` but that leaves a blank space above the keyboard equal to the height of the removed view & this is probably wrong
- **Problem 2**: How do I call the override method again and **return** another custom input accessory view?

**Here is how I add the first input accessory view**

```
lazy var customInputAccessoryViewNumberOne: KeyboardView = {
        let civ = KeyboardView(frame: .init(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: 50))
        civ.sendButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleSend), for: .touchUpInside)
        return civ
    }()

override var inputAccessoryView: UIView? {
        get {
             return customInputAccessoryViewNumberOne
        }
    }
```

Now when a user clicks on a button, I need to **completely replace** `customInputAccessoryViewNumberOne` with `customInputAccessoryViewNumberTwo`

```
@objc func handleNewInputAccessoryViewPressed() {
  //how to remove customInputAccessoryViewNumberOne?
  //how to add customInputAccessoryViewNumberTwo?
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently the override method gets called every time the keyboard is presented or dismissed (and it gets called multiple times as it is being presented or dismissed in order to render out the view based on the current position of the keyboard).
We can replace input accessory using a simple flag and if statement in the `override var inputAccessoryView` method by returning the appropriate UIView().

-To dimiss or show keyboard so that the view can be changed use **willBecomeFirstResponder** and **resignFirstResponder**

Answer (score 4):

You can simply do it by two steps

#### STEP 1:

Set your input accessory view when condition is meet

#### Step 2:

Call `reloadInputViews()` on your instance of `UITextField` or `UITextView`.

The following code snippet explains it.

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    let finalText = (textField.text as NSString?)?.replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)
    
    guard let txt = finalText else { return true }
    if txt.count > 5 {
        let greenView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 40))
        greenView.backgroundColor = .green
        textField.inputAccessoryView = greenView
    } else {
        let redView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 40))
        redView.backgroundColor = .red
        textField.inputAccessoryView = redView
    }
    textField.reloadInputViews()
    return true
}
```

[image]

Comment: This is a good solution but in my case, the textfield is located in the input accessory view. It is a chat app so the textfield is the input accessory view with an extra send button.