# swift UIViewController reload inputAccessoryView

Tags: ios, swift

I have a structure:

```
UITabBarController (2 tabs) -> UISplitViewController -> UINavigationController -> ViewController
```

In first viewcontroller I replaced tabbar with inputAccessoryView

```
class AViewController: UIViewController {
    override var inputAccessoryView: UIView? {
        return someView()
    }
}
```

in AViewController I programmatically need show the second tabbar item

```
func presentSecondTabBar() {
    let tabbar = self.tabBarController
    tabbar?.selectedIndex = 1
}
```

and when I present the second `tabbar` item then `inputAccessoryView` will replace with tabbar BUT when come back to `AViewController` (pressing to first tabBar item in `tabBarController`) `AViewController` still have tabbar, doesn't present a `inputAccessoryView`

I tried to reload the `inputAccessoryView` in `AViewController`, but didn't help.

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    inputAccessoryView?.becomeFirstResponder()
    
    view.reloadInputViews()
    view.layoutIfNeeded()
    inputAccessoryView?.updateConstraints()
    inputAccessoryView?.setNeedsLayout()
    inputAccessoryView?.layoutIfNeeded()
    inputAccessoryView?.reloadInputViews()
}
```

Can u help me?

Comment: Did you try calling TabBar's didSelectItem and try to manipulate it from there?

Comment: @LawrenceGimenez yes, I tried to delegate and listen tabBarController...didSelect method and then call reload inputAccessoryView, but didn't help

Comment: I believe you have to go the didSelect route and from there get the selectedViewController from TabBar and then initialize it again from there? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitabbarcontroller/1621172-selectedviewcontroller

Comment: @LawrenceGimenez how to initialize it again ? can u give an example ? thank you!

Comment: This might help you, reloading or re-initialize your view https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63724802/how-to-remove-inputaccessoryview-and-replace-it-with-another-view